# PHP JSON decode into a array just showing first character

Tags: php, json, session

I'm calling an API that returns the following output:

```
{"status":"OK","id":"2321","password":"f4f4489dcf95c16a31f9fb4ffff329fc","server":"pptpd"}
```

The ouput below has the *id* value and *password* value.

I coded that in **PHP** to decode the output and store this values in *SESSION*.

```
$update_mk = new \Core\Helpers\Driver;
$response = $update_mk->addNode($node->getId(),'admin','pass');

$decoded = json_decode($response, TRUE);
// I also tried without the TRUE argument but same result

$_SESSION['node_id'] = $decoded['id'][0];
$_SESSION['mk_password'] = $decoded['password'][0];

echo("node_id value: ");
echo($_SESSION['node_id']);
echo "\n";
echo("mk_password value: ");
echo($_SESSION['mk_password']);
```

The problem I'm having here, it's if I try to dump the value, it just show that:

```
node_id value: 370 mk_password value: f
```

It's **just showing the first character in mk_password**

What's wrong?

Comment: $_SESSION['node_id'] = $decoded['id'][0]; just remove [0] and you should be ready to go because with 0 it would only take the first character

Comment: thanks @Fabio, noob question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is because you're accessing it wrong way.

what is going on actually is:

you password `f4f4489dcf95c16a31f9fb4ffff329fc` is an array of characters.

something like this `$chars[0] = 'f'; $chars[1] = 4; $chars[2] = f;`

and you're getting `f` only just because you're accessing the first `index` of `array` that is `f`.

in order to make it work, you need to assign variable value instead of accessing it's first `index`

Here is little snippet that will help you to understand.

```
$json = '{"status":"OK","id":"2321","password":"f4f4489dcf95c16a31f9fb4ffff329fc","server":"pptpd"}';

$json = json_decode($json, TRUE);

echo "Status: ".$json['status'].PHP_EOL;
echo "ID: ".$json['id'].PHP_EOL;
echo "Password: ".$json['password'].PHP_EOL;
echo "Server: ".$json['server'].PHP_EOL;
```

outputs

```
Status: OK
ID: 2321
Password: f4f4489dcf95c16a31f9fb4ffff329fc
Server: pptpd
```

Check this **[Demo](http://ideone.com/LRhyBs)**

Comment: A little more explanation would be great for a good answer, this looks like a comment

Comment: @Fabio: I was in the middle of Edit when you commented :)